# How to parse array of arrays from string in column of csv/dataframe

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, csv, nested-lists

I have a csv file that contains a numpy array in one column. When reading the csv file, the resulting column will be of type character, since it's all wrapped in a string.
I'd like to parse it into a separate dataframe to analyse the data.

### Input data

As csv:

```
first_column,second_column
a,"[[1,2],[3,4]]"
b,"[[5,6],[7,8]]"
c,"[[9,10],[11,12]]"
```

As dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(first_column  = c("a","b","c"),
                 second_column = c("[[1,2],[3,4]]","[[5,6],[7,8]]","[[9,10],[11,12]]"))
```

### What I have tried

Since I am unaware of any direct parsing function that could extract arrays from strings, I have started out doing string manipulation.

Remove the outer `[]` characters:

```
> df %>% mutate(second_column = str_replace_all(second_column, c("^\\[" = "","]$" = "")))
  first_column  second_column
1            a    [1,2],[3,4]
2            b    [5,6],[7,8]
3            c [9,10],[11,12]
```

However, from now on I don't know how to proceed.

### Expected output

The resulting dataframe should look like this in the end:

```
  col_1 col_2
1     1     2
2     3     4
3     5     6
4     7     8
5     9    10
6    11    12
```

Note that there are more columns and more rows in the real dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace occurrences of ],[ with newline, replace square brackets with spaces and use `read.table` to read that.

```
df$second_column |>
  gsub("\\],\\[", "\n", x = _) |>
  chartr("[]", "  ", x = _) |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = ",")
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2
1  1  2
2  3  4
3  5  6
4  7  8
5  9 10
6 11 12
```

Comment: This looks neat! This will result in a wide table layout: When the CSV has 10 rows and the nested table has a 10x10 size, then the resulting table will be 10 x 100 (10x10 = 100)

Answer (score 2):

A *base* variant could be:

```
#Replace [], with space
. <- gsub("[][,]", " ", df$second_column)
#. <- chartr("[],", "   ",  df$second_column) #Alternativ

#Split at "   " and unlist result
. <- unlist(strsplit(., "   ", fixed=TRUE))
#. <- sub("   ", "\n", ., fixed=TRUE) #Alternativ

#use read.table to get columns
read.table(text = .)
#  V1 V2
#1  1  2
#2  3  4
#3  5  6
#4  7  8
#5  9 10
#6 11 12
```

or using `trimws`

```
. <- trimws(df$second_column, whitespace = "[][]")

. <- unlist(strsplit(., "],[", fixed=TRUE))
#. <- sub("],[", "\n", ., fixed=TRUE) #Alternativ

read.csv(text=.)
```

Comment: In this solution, the resulting table has a long layout: When the CSV has 10 rows and the nested table has a 10x10 size, then the resulting table will be 100 x 10 (with x 10 being the number of columns in the nested array)

Comment: Can you give an example and expected output for that case?

Comment: It's alright, this form suits me best. Since it's a series of observations, I extracted it in a separate df and then further filtered for one entity by `obs[seq(1,nrow(obs),10,]` (with `obs.` being the extracted df) But I didn't ask for that here

Answer (score 1):

A **base R** approach that deals with any number of rows on the given columns.

```
setNames(
  data.frame(Vectorize(\(x) as.numeric(x))(
    data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
      sapply(lapply(strsplit(df$second_column, "\\],\\["), 
          gsub, pattern="\\[|\\]", replacement=""), strsplit, ","))))), 
  c("col_1", "col_2"))
  col_1 col_2
1     1     2
2     3     4
3     5     6
4     7     8
5     9    10
6    11    12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky solution using `tidyverse`:

```r
df <- data.frame(first_column  = c("a","b","c"),
                 second_column = c("[[1,2],[3,4]]","[[5,6],[7,8]]","[[9,10],[11,12]]"))

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(second_column = str_replace_all(second_column, c("^\\[" = "","]$" = "")),
         second_column = gsub("\\[|\\]", "", second_column)) %>% 
  separate(second_column, into = c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4"), sep = ",") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-first_column) %>% 
  mutate(name = case_when(name == "col_3" ~ "col_1",
                          name == "col_4" ~ "col_2", 
                          .default = name)) %>% 
  select(-first_column) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(col_1, col_2))
  
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   col_1 col_2
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1     2    
#> 2 3     4    
#> 3 5     6    
#> 4 7     8    
#> 5 9     10   
#> 6 11    12
```

Answer (score 0):

A trick with `py_eval` from `reticulate`

```
library(reticulate)
with(
  df,
  as.data.frame(
    do.call(
      rbind,
      py_eval(gsub("]], [[", "],[",
        toString(second_column),
        fixed = TRUE
      ))
    )
  )
)
```

or another trick with `fromJSON` from `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
with(
  df,
  as.data.frame(
    fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", gsub("]], [[", "],[",
      toString(second_column),
      fixed = TRUE
    )))[1, , ]
  )
)
```

## Output

```
  V1 V2
1  1  2
2  3  4
3  5  6
4  7  8
5  9 10
6 11 12
```